# Как найти определенную последовательность в массиве объектов в js?

Tags: javascript

К примеру есть 2 массива объектов.

```
let arr1 = [ { value: '2'}, { value: '4'}, { value: '11'}, { value: '7'}, { value: '8'}, { value: '9'} ];

let arr2 = [ { value: '5'}, { value: '20'}, { value: '5'}, { value: '7'}, { value: '9'}, { value: '11'} ];
```

В массиве arr1 последние 3 элемента будут восходящей последовательностью (7, 8, 9)
В массиве arr2 последние 4 элемента будут восходящей последовательностью (5, 7, 9, 11)
В похожих массивах такие последовательности будут всегда последними элементами массива

Перед началом последовательности, **всегда** будет значение, которое больше первого элемента последовательности. В arr1 это значение = 11, в arr2 это значение = 20

Помогите написать функцию, которая будет возвращать эту последовательность при условии, что первый элемент перед ней > первого элемента начала последовательности

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).